# Compare two JSON arrays and iterate over the remaining items

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have two arrays with numbers that are already stored in variables:

```
$SLOT_IDS = [1,2,3,4,5]
$PR_IDS = [3,4]
```

I would like to find which numbers are in array 1 but not array 2. So in this case it would be

$OBSOLETE_SLOT_IDS = [1,2,5]

and then I would like to run a command foreach of those numbers and insert it into a placeholder:

So this command:

```
az webapp deployment slot delete -g group --name webapp --slot pr-<PLACEHOLDER>
```

Should be run three times:

```
az webapp deployment slot delete -g group --name webapp --slot pr-1
az webapp deployment slot delete -g group --name webapp --slot pr-2
az webapp deployment slot delete -g group --name webapp --slot pr-5
```

I know that should look something like this (it is required that it is inline):

```
for i in $OBSOLETE_SLOT_IDS; do az webapp deployment slot delete -g group --name webapp --slot pr-$i; done
```

So my questions:

1. How can I calculte $OBSOLETE_SLOT_IDS from the other two variables with an inline command
2. What is the correct version of the for loop

comment: seems that the variables do not contain actual arrays. They are basically the return values of some curl calls that I stored in variables:

[image]

Comment: `$SLOT_IDS = [1,2,3,4,5]` isn't legal bash array syntax. Please show us _exactly_ how your values are stored.

Comment: (note that in `for i in $OBSOLETE_SLOT_IDS`, `OBSOLETE_SLOT_IDS` isn't an array at all either; it's a string you're splitting and globbing into a list of words, but you _should_ be using an array instead -- see [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005) for an introduction to arrays in bash).

Comment: ...also existing is [BashFAQ #36](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036), which is exactly on point for "how do I diff two arrays?"

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my question

Comment: Okay, so it's a string with JSON. You'll want to either use jq or python; bash has no built-in JSON parser -- jq is the usual tool used to bridge that gap, but if you don't have it and can't install it, `python` is basically always preinstalled on modern, non-embedded systems.

Comment: I actually used jq to parse the curl response:

PR_IDS=$(curl --user "$BITBUCKET_USER:$BITBUCKET_PASSWORD" https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/xxx/xxx/pullrequests?q=state%3D%22OPEN%22 | jq '.values[].id' | jq --slurp 'flatten')

Comment: If you _didn't_ use that second `jq --slurp 'flatten'` call, what would your output be? (If it would be one number per line, that might actually be easier to work with).

Comment: yes, it would one number in each line

Comment: When you say "required that it is inline", do you mean required that it's _a single_ line, or did you mean something else? If something else, what exactly?

Comment: yes, it should be in one line so I can add it as a script step to a yml file. Thanks for all you help

Comment: YAML supports multi-line strings just fine. You don't need a one liner for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jq -r '.[]'` will transform your array to a stream with one number per line -- which is the format that standard UNIX tools expect to work with.

Once we have the numbers in a sorted form, we can use `comm` to compare the two streams. `-3` tells `comm` to ignore contents present in both streams, and `-2` tells it to ignore content present only in the second stream, so `comm -23` prints only files unique to the first stream.

Using `readarray` (added in bash 4.0) then lets us read that content into an array, which we can iterate over in our `for` loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
slot_ids='[1,2,3,4,5]'
pr_ids='[3,4]'

readarray -t filtered_slot_ids <(
  comm -23 \
    <(jq -r '.[]' <<<"$slot_ids" | sort) \
    <(jq -r '.[]' <<<"$pr_ids" | sort))

for i in "${filtered_slot_ids[@]}"; do
  az webapp deployment slot delete -g group --name webapp --slot "pr-$i"
done
```

Comment: `readarray -t filtered_slot_ids < <(jq -n --argjson a "$slot_ids" --argjson b "$pr_ids" '$a - $b |  .[]')` is a simpler way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

A shorter approach that uses `jq` to get the difference of the two arrays:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

slot_ids="[1,2,3,4,5]"
pr_ids="[3,4]"

while read -r id; do
    az webapp deployment slot delete -g group --name webapp --slot "pr-$id"
done < <(jq -n --argjson a "$slot_ids" --argjson b "$pr_ids" '$a - $b | .[]')
```

Comment: This one also reads the `jq` output directly instead of using an intermediate array. Figured, the fewer lines the better if this is going in a yaml file.